# how insert input 1 value to more input in jquery

Tags: jquery

In my view, i have many input, how can i insert input first to another input in keyup, this is my code :

```js
$(document).ready(function()
 {
   $("#costForAll").keyup(function()
   {
      $("#cost").val($("#costForAll").val());
   });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<input id="costForAll">
</div>

<form>
<tr>
<td>
<input id="cost" type="number" class="form-control">
<input id="cost" type="number" class="form-control">
<input id="cost" type="number" class="form-control">
<input id="cost" type="number" class="form-control">
<input id="cost" type="number" class="form-control">
<input id="cost" type="number" class="form-control">
<input id="cost" type="number" class="form-control">
<input id="cost" type="number" class="form-control">
<input id="cost" type="number" class="form-control">
</td>
</tr>
</form>
```

this code working for me, but just on first (id="cost")

please help me, thank's all

Comment: _"this code working for me, but just on first (id="cost")"_ - Because ids have to be **unique**

Comment: @Andreas thanks for comment , Instead of entering the cost value manually, I want to enter the value field and assign it to all other fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use id's unique but still you can update values like this

```
$(document).ready(function()
     {
       $("#costForAll").keyup(function()
       {
          $("input[id=cost]").each((i,n)=>{
            n.value = $("#costForAll").val();
          })
       });
    
    });
```